# Writing an array to a text file

Tags: python-2.7, multidimensional-array

So I have this array, say it's

```
import numpy as np
m = np.array([[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]])
```

and I want to write its dimension to a text file, and then I want to write the array itself below that.

I've already accomplished this somewhat with

```
with open(filepath, 'w') as f:
    n = len(m)
    f.write(str(n) + ' \n')
    np.savetxt(f, m)
```

The problem is that in the file the numbers are written as floats and I want them as they were given--as ints!  As far as I can tell savetxt() has no setting for this.

And I've tried switching from using savetxt() to using tofile() but this won't even write the array to a file, I assume because I've written something else to the file first and that's somehow messing with its operation.

I guess I could just write it by making a for loop, but that seems less ideal than just having a function out there waiting for me to use it, if that exists.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but it saves the array as it is, in this case the elements are all floats:

```
import numpy as np
m= np.array([[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]])

filepath = '/Path/to/file/'
fout = open(filepath + 'fout.dat', 'w')

# I'd use this if you want the full shape of the array
dimensions = np.shape(m)
print >>fout, str(dimensions) + ' \dimensions'
print >>fout, m 

fout.close()
```

Hope this helps..